# text to ascii in java

Tags: java, ascii

Hello i was wondering to convert text in java to ascii

Comment: ASCII is very limited - please explain what your input is and what your output is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert text to ASCII you can do

```
String text = "Hello World!";
byte[] ascii = text.getBytes("US-ASCII");
```

Answer (score 1):

you mean smth like

```
String str;
int[] asciiCodes = new int[str.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i ++) {
  asciiCodes[i] = (int)str.charAt(i);
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear, but I guess you may want to write text using an `OutputStreamWriter` created with the US-ASCII character set:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ascii-file.txt");
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "US-ASCII");
writer.write("A string with accents éèà");
writer.close();
```